# Why can't I debug this very simple ASP.NET MVC3 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, http-status-code-404

I decided to follow [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3-part1-cs) tutorial on getting started with ASP.NET. I have Visual Web Developer 2010 Express (with SP1) installed, as well as the ASP.NET MVC3 tools.

I created the project and starting debugging it by going to `Debug->Start Debugging` - which then opened my browser to `http://localhost:50531` and displayed:

[image]

According to the tutorial, that's not what I'm supposed to see.

**Additional details:**

- OS: Windows Vista Home Premium 32-bit (with SP2)
- I also have IIS 7.0 installed and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use the presets or an empty project? If the latter, you don't have any controllers or views, thus the routing doesn't match anything, resulting in an error.

Comment: Hmmm... maybe I selected Empty Project by mistake. Let me check.

Comment: A good place to start when you see "missing file" messages in the local-host asp.net server, is your web.config (if its non existant the application will fail to run)